# How to extract date in dd-MMM-yyyy from string using regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string which contains a large amount of text and inside this text is a date in the format `dd-MM-yyyy`. An example of this text is as follows

`Composed by super, mtzshm to super, mtzshm on 31-Mar-2016 02:24 with Normal priority and Message Type General Message`

I would like the date part of the text to be extracted using Regex and for it to be converted into a DateTime

Comment: Do you need the date, or both date and time? Your original question also mentioned time, but subsequent edits lost this requirement. I've tried to edit your question to add time back in, but it was rejected somehow.

Answer (score 3):

For date time: `\d{2}-[A-z]{3}-\d{4}\s\d{2}:\d{2}`

For date: `\d{2}-[A-z]{3}-\d{4}`

```
\d{2}       Match a digit of length 2
-           Matches character '-'
[A-z]{3}    Matches a character in the Range 'A' to 'z' of length 3
[A-z]*      Matches a character in the Range 'A' to 'z' of length x
\s          Matches any white space character
:           Matches character ':'
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please format your code. This [meta-post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) include details about how to do that. Without reformatting, your post looks like gibberish and is hard to read.

Comment: `[A-z]` will match characters like `[`, `]` and `^`. Better use `[A-Za-z]`

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to know what the string will contains? Will it contain only DD-MM-YYYY or will it have other things?

If you pass only DD-MM-YYYY Already and want to turn it into a DateTime
you can do a simple for loop without the use of regular expression

```
string date = "DD-MM-YYYY";

string year = null;
string month = null;
string day = null;

for ( int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
   if ( i < 2)
     day += date[i];
   if ( i > 2 && i < 5 )
     month += date[i];
   if ( i > 5 )
     year += date[i];
}

DateTime date = new DateTime();
date = date.AddYears(Convert.ToInt32(year)-1);
date = date.AddMonths(Convert.ToInt32(month)-1);
date = date.AddDays(Convert.ToInt32(day-1);
```

This should work, just coded this directly on the site,
tell me if that's not what you need, since there is not enough explanation.

Edit : Nvm you want to get the 31-Mar-2016 , which means it is not a DD-MM-YYYY format but a DD-MMM-YYYY format which gives this regular expression :

```
^(([0-9])|([0-2][0-9])|([3][0-1]))\-(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\-\d{4}$
```

Answer (score 0):

Following regex will capture just **Date** part from given string.

```
\b\d{1,2}\-[a-z]{3}\-\d{4}\b
```

Final code should look like

```
var text = "Composed by super, mtzshm to super, mtzshm on 31-Mar-2016 02:24 with ";
text    += "Normal priority and Message Type General Message";

var rx = new Regex(@"\b\d{1,2}\-[a-z]{3}\-\d{4}\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);

var match = rx.Match(text);
if (match.Success)
{
    var dateString = match.Value;
    var date = DateTime.Parse(dateString);

    Console.WriteLine(date);
}
```

If everything goes well, you'll see a nice date printed in your local format. In my case it'see

```
3/31/2016 12:00:00 AM
```